# How do I draw an Ideal line between two headers?

Tags: html, css, markup

My HTML code has this structure:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

<body>
  ...
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Sub</h2>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

I want to "draw" a line between those two headings like this:

[image: title - sub]

It should adjust to the width of the headings:

[image: longer title - sub]

[image: title - longer subtitle]

(Excuse my image editing skills)

Is there a simple css-only way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this problem with a simply `pseudo` element. **No html structure changing** or **non-support css of cross browers**.
We need to use `table` display on the parent and make a new element (your border with `pseudo`) on the `<h1>`.

**Look at this example:**

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0 10px 5px;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    <h1>long long title</h1>
    <h2>Sub</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <h1>h1</h1>
    <h2>Sub</h2>
  </div>


 <div id="container">
    <h1>h1</h1>
    <h2>long long subtitle</h2>
  </div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/8tLny74v/)**

Comment: works perfectly - which is better, this or the accepted answer?

Comment: Flexbox dont support IE well, So, your choice.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and most flexible way i think is to use `Flexbox`. Just add some left and right padding to `h1` and `h2` elements so line can always be a bit longer then text.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem ispum</h1>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h2>Sub</h2>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Ispum</h1>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
</div>
```

Update: You can actually do this with  pseudo-element on `.container` but you need to specify order so that line shows after `h1` element.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.container > h1 {
  order: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.container > h2 {
  padding: 0 10px;
  order: 3;
}
.container:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem ispum</h1>
  <h2>Sub</h2>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Ispum</h1>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Why to use Flex and change the Html if its don't needed? You don't need to add span to this structure or use Flex (don't support on old IE versions)

Comment: How do I make this line printable? When I click on 'print', the line disappears

Comment: Did you use first or second example?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
} 

/* h2 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
} */
```